# xampp-This page cannot be displayed

Tags: mysql, apache, tomcat, xampp

Just download xampp. When I click Admin `button` to go to localHost,  **page cannot be displayed**.

[image]

Anyone know how to fix this ?

**Apache**

**http.conf** -`Listen 7777` , `ServerName localhost:7777`

**MySQL**

**my.ini** -`# password       = your_password 
port            = 3307 
socket          = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"`

**New error**

```
12:08:32 AM  [main]     You are not running with administrator rights! This will work for
12:08:32 AM  [main]     most application stuff but whenever you do something with services
12:08:32 AM  [main]     there will be a security dialogue or things will break! So think 
12:08:32 AM  [main]     about running this application with administrator rights!
12:08:32 AM  [main]     XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\"
12:08:32 AM  [main]     Checking for prerequisites
12:08:32 AM  [main]     All prerequisites found
12:08:32 AM  [main]     Initializing Modules
12:08:32 AM  [main]     Starting Check-Timer
12:08:32 AM  [main]     Control Panel Ready
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your **port is not available** for it, Or some other programe is using this port number. you may have to **change your port** for the server

Comment: I change to 7777, still cannot

Comment: try running Xampp as administrator

Answer (score 0):

Before getting access to local host make sure your skype is not running.

Comment: I don't have skype :(

Comment: Why don't you use default 80 port?